# Multiple subtotal in grand total in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to calculate subtotal in grand total, subtotals are in class/id= amount and id=sum. I want to add/sum with SUM and amount, amount1 values as a grand total.

Sum values are bandwidth, cpus, ram, hardware, mailbox storage box(multiplying with quantity) and bulk storage box(multiplying with quantity).

Mailbox storage box and bulk storage box are two subtotals.
and bandwidth, cpus, ram, hardware are subtotal of SUM.
So want to grandtotal of subtotals(mailbox, bulk and sum) as in grandtotal.

kindly advice.

```js
function calculateSum() {
  var sum = 0;
  var bw = 4000;
  var ccpu = 25000;
  var chd = 650;
  var cram = 20000;
  var conetimecost = 1;
  //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
  $(".costbandwidth").each(function() {
    //a dd only if the value is number
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      //check cooresponding quantity
      var qty = $(this).parents('tr').find('.net-bw').val();
      sum += (parseFloat(this.value) * bw);
    }
  });
  $(".costcpu").each(function() {
    //add only if the value is number
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      //check cooresponding quantity
      var qty = $(this).parents('tr').find('.net-cpu').val();
      sum += (parseFloat(this.value) * ccpu);
    }
  });
  $(".costharddisk").each(function() {
    //add only if the value is number
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      //check cooresponding quantity
      var qty = $(this).parents('tr').find('.net-hd').val();
      sum += (parseFloat(this.value) * chd);
    }
  });
  $(".cost_ram").each(function() {
    //add only if the value is number
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      //check cooresponding quantity
      var qty = $(this).parents('tr').find('.net-ram').val();
      sum += (parseFloat(this.value) * cram);
    }
  });
  $(".onetimecost").each(function() {
    //add only if the value is number
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      //check cooresponding quantity
      var qty = $(this).parents('tr').find('.net-one').val();
      sum += (parseFloat(this.value) * conetime);
    }
  });
  $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".txt").keyup(function() {
    calculateSum();
  });
  $('.net-bw, .net-cpu,.net-hd, .net-ram, .net-one').on('change', function() {
    calculateSum();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  update_amounts();
  $('.quantity').change(function() {
    update_amounts();
  });
  $('.price').change(function() {
    update_amounts();
  });
  update_amount();
  $('.quantity1').change(function() {
    update_amount();
  });
  $('.price1').change(function() {
    update_amount();
  });
});

function update_amounts() {
  var sum = 0.0;
  $('#myTable > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
    var price = $(this).find('.price').val();
    var qa = $(this).find('.quantity').val();
    var amount = (qa * price);
    sum += amount;
    $(this).find('.amount').text('' + amount);
  });
}

function update_amount() {
  var sum = 0.0;
  $('#myTable > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
    var price = $(this).find('.price1').val();
    var qa = $(this).find('.quantity1').val();
    var amount = (qa * price);
    sum += amount;
    $(this).find('.amount1').text('' + amount);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="form1" action="save_data.php">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="field_wrapper" id="InputsWrapper">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field"><button class=" btn btn-primary" style=" margin:5px;">Add More Field</button></a>
      <table id="myTable">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label> Customer Name</label> 
            <input class="form-control customer" placeholder="Enter Customer name" type="text" name="customer_name[]" required/>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label> One Time Cost</label> <input class="form-control onetimecost txt" placeholder="Enter one time Cost" type="number" name="one_time_cost[]" required/></td>
          <td class="net-one total"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label> Bandwidth Mbps</label>  <input class="form-control costbandwidth txt" type="number" name="bandwidth[]" min="1" max="32" required/></td>
          </td>
          <td class="net-bw total"></td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault" name="name[]">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">CIR</label>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckChecked" name="name[]">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked">Shared</label>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label> Cpu  Core'S</label> <input class="form-control costcpu txt" placeholder="Enter CPU Core's" type="number" name="cpu[]" min="1" max="5" required/></td>
          <td class="net-cpu total"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> <label> Hard Disk GB</label> <input class="form-control costharddisk txt" placeholder="Enter Hard Disk GB" type="number" name="hard_disk[]" min="1" max="5000" required/></td>
          <td class="net-hd total"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label> Ram GB</label> <input class="form-control cost_ram txt" placeholder="Enter Ram GB" type="number" name="ram[]" min="1" max="12" required/></td>
          <td class="net-ram total"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label> Email</label> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="type " timezone_abbreviations_list id="chkPassport" />Bulk storage box 
            <input class="form-control quantity1" placeholder="Enter quantity " type="number" name="quantity[]" min="1" max="5000" required/>
            <select name="CPU" id="CPU1" class="price1">
              <option value="">Select Mailbox</option>
              <option value="17915" data-price="17915">100,000 MB</option>
              <option value="26875" data-price="26875">150,000 MB</option>
              <option value="35830" data-price="35830">200,000 MB</option>
              <option value="44790" data-price="44790">250,000 MB</option>
              <option value="53750" data-price="53750">300,000 MB</option>
              <option value="62705" data-price="62705">350,000 MB</option>
              <option value="89580" data-price="89580">500,000 MB</option>
              <option value="98535" data-price="98535">550,000 MB</option>
              <option value="103915" data-price="103915">580,000 MB</option>
              <option value="179160" data-price="179160">1,000,000 MB</option>
              <option value="358320" data-price="358320">2,000,000 MB</option>
              <option value="537480" data-price="537480">3,000,000 MB</option>
              <option value="716635" data-price="716635">4,000,000 MB</option>
              <option value="895795" data-price="895795">5,000,000 MB</option>
              <option value="1074955" data-price="1074955">6,000,000 MB</option>
              <option value="1433270" data-price="1433270">8,000,000 MB</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td align="center"><span id="amount1" class="amount1 subtotal">  0  </span> Rs</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="type " timezone_abbreviations_list id="chkPassport" />Mail storage box 
            <input class="form-control quantity" placeholder="Enter quantity " type="number" name="quantity[]" min="1" max="5000" required/>
            <select name="CPU" id="CPU" class="price">
              <option value="">Select Mailbox</option>
              <option value="40" data-price="40">50 MB</option>
              <option value="75" data-price="75">100 MB</option>
              <option value="135" data-price="135">200 MB</option>
              <option value="270" data-price="270">500 MB</option>
              <option value="430" data-price="430">1000 MB</option>
              <option value="690" data-price="690">2000 MB</option>
              <option value="1105" data-price="1105">4000 MB</option>
              <option value="1245" data-price="1245">5000 MB</option>
              <option value="1330" data-price="1330">6000 MB</option>
              <option value="1590" data-price="1590">8000 MB</option>
              <option value="1790" data-price="1790">10000 MB</option>
              <option value="3580" data-price="3580">20000 MB</option>
              <option value="5730" data-price="5730">32000 MB</option>
              <option value="8960" data-price="8960">50000 MB</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td align="center"><span id="amount" class="amount subtotal">  0</span> Rs</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><label> SSl</label> 
            <select class="form-control ssl txt" name="sssl[]" id="ssl" required>
              <option value="">No Selected</option>
              <option value="single-domain">Single Domain DV</option>
              <option value="wildcard">Wild Card DV</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label> Antivirus</label> 
            <input class="form-control cost_vss txt" type="text" name="antivirus[]" required/>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="summation">
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right"> sum:   </td>
          <td align="center"><span id="sum" class="subtotal"> 0.00 </span></td> 
          <td class="total"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Your HTML shows a lot of `'?>`'s. Please fix the structure.  Reading [ask] might help since we'll need a [mre] to help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I have converted your Example Code into a Snippet. Please be aware that you should not use HTML inside your Script tags. You have `<br />` on the end of each line and this is not needed. The code you provided is from PHP. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example that is the resulting HTML and not the PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Remove php , ?> and br